# How can I use Target.Address with offset

Tags: excel, vba

The purpose of my code is to copy from columns in the same row as the cell 'G4' when cell contents are changed. However, nothing is happening when I change G4's contents.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change3(ByVal Target As Range)
    
        If Target.Address = "$G$4" Then
            Range("G4").Select
            Selection.Offset(0, -6).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count + 0, _
            Selection.Columns.Count + 2).Copy
        End If 
     End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't copy the value of A4:C4 ?

Comment: Shorter as: `If Target.Address = "$G$4" Then Me.Range("A4:C4").Copy`   There's no need to select a range to work with it.

Comment: ...if that's not what you're looking for then a little more context around what your code is intended to do would help.

Comment: Why don't you share your complete code from `Sub...` to `End Sub` and explain why you're using such an unusual way to reference the range to be copied and where it should be pasted to (if not obvious from the code). Also, make sure the code is in the correct sheet module (e.g. `Sheet1`). You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72624079/edit) at any time.

Comment: @TimWilliams I simplified the code to try and find the problem, originally it was to use target.address to carry out a loop to copy cells from column A-C when the contents from column G are changed

Comment: `Worksheet_Change3` will not run when you make a change on the sheet, because that's not the correct name - needs to be `Worksheet_Change` to capture the event...

Answer (score 0):

To copy columns A:C on a row when the value in ColG is changed you could try something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
   If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
   
   If Target.Column = 7 Then Target.EntireRow.Range("A1:C1").Copy
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Copy Columns in the Same Row

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Reference the source cell.
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = Range("G4")
    
    ' 'Target' could be multiple cells e.g. if you paste a range. To check
    ' if one of those cells is the source cell and to attempt to reference it,
    ' use 'Intersect':
    Dim iCell As Range: Set iCell = Intersect(sCell, Target)
    
    ' Use the following line to check if 'iCell' is a range (or 'Nothing'):
    If Not iCell Is Nothing Then
        ' Reference columns 'A:C' in the row of the source cell
        ' by using 'EntireRow' with 'Columns':
        Dim irg As Range: Set irg = iCell.EntireRow.Columns("A:C")
        ' Copy the range.
        irg.Copy
    ' Else 'iCell' is 'Nothing' i.e. 'sCell' is not a cell of 'Target'
    End If

End Sub
```